# Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device it wont load CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

website running properly in desktop browser even when I resize the browser size, but when I open it in the mobile it seems that it won't load CSS and JS files. I don't know why.

Please open this link in desktop browser as well as mobile browser also, so you will get proper idea.

I already tried to add

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in header but it won't fix.

Comment: well. It does not add the css and js in desktop too.

Comment: It doesn't load css on desktop too. You leave the localhost url on all script and css link tag so you can see it just on computer you working on.

Comment: Please do not add just a link add some code

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Worth a read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Open console(F12) and you will see that all your resources are not being loaded. Because the URLs are set from localhost. Now load them one by one and you will be good to go. Make sure that there is no error here.

Comment: yaah..thanxx a lot bro...that's the only issue...but in my pc its works properly becoz of cookie...thanxx a lot again

Comment: You are welcome. And just to make your concept clear. On your PC it is working because the files are in your localhost server but when you go to other PC there is not such file in their localhost environment. It is a problem I guess every web developer goes through at least once. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You are using `http://localhost` in your CSS URLs. Please use relative paths.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/cv/css/style.css"/>
```

change to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

**please note** to also remove the `/cv` part as that doesn't seem to be right.

---

## Explanation

`http://localhost` is pointing to your own local server so it wil work on your development device but not when accessing the site via `http://yashnagariya.me` on any other device.